# Photoshop + Wine tooltip doesn't go away problem

Tags: ubuntu, adobe-photoshop, wine

I'm running Photoshop CS5 on Wine with Ubuntu Linux. 
Now it's working great however there's an annoying problem: 
If you leave your mouse on a file name when you start photoshop, 
a tooltip opens up that mentions the file path (yellow floating thingy). 
However, in Wine it doesn't go away until the program closes. 
It's floating over other windows as well.

Comment: The correct place for this is in the Wine forums

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Try disabling Tool Tips.**

*Steps to disable*

- Go to Edit
- Select Preferences
- Preferences window pop-ups
- under Interface, uncheck "Show tool tips"

[image]

Comment: On newer editions of Photoshop, this is found on the Tools section of Preferences

Comment: THANK YOU! On CS6 it's Edit>Preferences>General.  Dug out my old license and was getting annoyed with this.